# Getting exact string from a txt file

Tags: python, regex, text-files

Let's say I am trying to get the number of times "the" appears in a text file. How do I get the word "the" alone by itself :

> Without getting others words with '**the**' as a substring like :
>
> - "there",
> - "them",
> - "their", etc.

Comment: How bout this '/\b(the)\b/g' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
word = 'the'
reg = re.compile(r'\b%s\b' % word, re.I)
with open('textfile.containing.the','r') as fin:
     print(len(reg.findall(fin.read()))
```

Hope that helps..

Answer (score 1):

**[Online Demo](http://regex101.com/r/iS2yG1)**

How bout this `/\b(the)\b/g` ?

**`\b`** asserts at a word boundary

Answer (score 1):

Using re.search and a counter.

```
import re
count =0
with open("test.txt")  as f:
    for line in f:
        if re.search(r"\bthe$",line): # if search does not find a match it will return None
            count+=1
```